# Oozie job.properties variable issue

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

In my job.properties I have defined username as `usrname=$USERNAME` where `USERNAME` variable is echoed from another shell script.
If I do `echo $USERNAME` i get the correct username.
In the workflow.xml, this username is passed as `${usrname}`.

However the job is failing because of invalid username and in the log, I can see the username as `$USERNAME` not the actual value.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to replace the value during runtime in the properties file.

Comment: In other words, _" If I do `echo $USERNAME`"_ implies you running commands inside a **Linux shell interpreter** and it's the shell that does variable substitution based on environment variables. Oozie is a **java application**; at best you could try a Java system property like `${user.name}` directly, instead of your custom `${usrname}` and see if Oozie recognizes that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed variable to read from pom.xml and the issue is resolved.